# How to read a packet that used memcpy

Tags: c, memory, stm32, packet

```
    uint8_t sendPacket[200];
    
    float a = 22.0f;  

char buffer[4] ={0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04};


    memcpy(&buffer, &a, sizeof(a));
    memcpy(sendPacket+92,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
            
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart7, (uint8_t*)sendPacket, length+5, 0xFFFF);
```

I use the code above, but I know memcpy copies the memory, but when I looked at the value in Packet, the value came out so weird

There are other chords on top, but it's almost repeated, so I took it out

It's supposed to be transmitted through Bluetooth, but it comes out properly in the place where it's transmitted through Bluetooth, but it comes out weird

First of all, I want to send the packet in stm32 to another place to get the value, The result of the live watch is the same as in the picture

a contains float value

[image]

Comment: We have no idea what `Time` and `dust21` are. And we also have no idea what you expect to be in `sendPacket`. What do you expect from us?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you expect. and there are some unknowns like dust21 and Time. But at the receiver you need to create a float from the bytes again. looking at a float value in bytes form is not intuitive. also why are you doing the step with buffer first and not copy to sendPacket right away?

Comment: Why do you use an intermediate buffer? You could copy from "Time" and "a" into "sendPacket". Maybe "sizeof(buffer)" is not enough?

Comment: I want a way to read the value of a from the packet

Comment: The code you provide above is to format the value of `a` into `sendPacket`, rather than read from `sendPacket`. What's issue now?

Answer (score 1):

To read the float again you could for instance memcpy into a float:

```cpp
float a_received = 0.0f;
memcpy(&a_received, &sendPacket[92], sizeof(a_received));
```

As user694733 pointed out, using memcpy.

Comment: Downvoted: `*(float*)&sendPacket[92]` is strict aliasing violation and also possibly misaligned access. Use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: @user694733 could you give more information about the risk of this way? because I always used like this way.

Comment: @Sean C standard states that you cannot dereference pointer using non-matching type (with some exceptions). Doing so leads to *undefined behaviour*, which means anything can happen. In practice, it can cause compiler that relies on type based aliasing rules to generate invalid binary code. It can be worked around using compiler specific settings, but then code is no longer conforming to standard and less portable. In summary: If it worked for you in the past, then you just got unlucky; it hasn't failed you yet.

Comment: @Sean And misaligned access simply means that some processors require that data that is accessed is aligned to certain way. For example, `float` address must typically be divisible by 4, or you get crash, data corruption or some other misbehaviour.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks for you kind explanation. I just had a quick check, then realized that I never used in C but only in C++. Does C++ allow this way?

Comment: @Sean Unfortunately C++ inherited aliasing rules from C, so same applies there too.

Comment: @user694733 Then I'm really lucky.

Comment: @Sean: on some architectures, allowing misaligned access would come with a significant general performance penalty, so the C/C++ standards cannot allow it. On other architectures there is no problem. Also, in this case if the buffer is 4-byte aligned, then offset 92 is also 4-byte aligned and then there is *probably* no issue. From a standard perspective, however, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

" when I looked at the value in Packet, the value came out so weird"

When you look in `sendPacket`what you see is raw bytes. To check whether you have copied the right float at the right place you need to interpret the 4 bytes from your array to a float value. It is basically what a debugger or a `printf` would do.

For exemple the number `22.0f` is represented in IEE754 floating number representation  by `0x41b00000` so you should see in your array `00 00 b0 41` for example on a little endian system.